# Cutting string by first number found

Tags: php, explode, preg-split

I have to cut the first part of my string before any number found. For example:

string: "BOBOSZ 27A lok.6" should be cutted to 'BOBOSZ "

string: "aaa 43543" should be cutted to "aaa "

string: "aa2bhs2" should be cutted to "aa"

Im trying with preg_split and explode funcionts but i can't get the right result for now.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why you don't have the space in the first and second string?

Comment: Yep, you're right it should be cutted to 'BOBOSZ ' and 'aaa ', i will correct my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern with the `preg_match()` function:

```
preg_match('/^[^0-9]+/', $str, $match);
print_r($match);
```

pattern details:

```
^         # anchor: start of the string
[^0-9]+   # negated character class: all that is not a digit one or more times
```

note: you can replace `+` by `*` if you consider that an empty string is a valid result.

If you absolutly want to use the `preg_split()` function, you do:

```
$result = preg_split('/(?=(?:[^0-9].*)?$)/s', $str);
echo $result[0];
```

Comment: After using $answer = preg_split('/^[^0-9]+/', $adress[0]);    I got "array (size=2)  0 => string '' (length=0)  1 => string '27A lok.6' (length=9)" First string is empty and second string is the second part, but I need this first part...

Comment: @69punk: refresh the page.

Comment: you're right, preg_match works better in this case. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('#(\w+)\s?\d+#', $string, $match);
```

You should get $match[1] as I remember :)